# Up method is not working correctly in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am working with Sencha Touch and I have the next codeline

```
var formpanel = button.getParent().getParent().down('formpanel'); //working correctly but tricky
```

I am using two "getParent()" because the "up" method is not working for me

```
var formpanel = button.up('formpanel'); //No-working
```

and the view

```
items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: 'test',
                docked: 'top',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    iconCls: 'info',
                    style:{
                        'margin-left': '75em'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                layout: 'hbox',
                scrollable: null,
                items: []
            }
```

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Is the button a direct child of the form? You didn't show your structure, so it's not possible to answer.

Comment: You can't use `up`, because the form is not an ancestor of the button.

Comment: Any suggestion @EvanTrimboli  ??  thanks!

Comment: You have something that already works. What else do you want?

Comment: For example :                             var formpanel = button.getParent().getParent().down('formpanel');  It´s working properly but I think is ugly...  :-)  two getParents()..

Comment: Evan is correct that you're traversing correctly. You can't just use 'up' in this situation. If you really need it neater, use up to the parent container (the view which has not specified in this example but owns the items) and down again e.g. `button.up("ItemIdOfContainer").down("formpanel");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work because according to [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-up):

`up( [selector] ) :`Walks up the ownerCt axis looking for **an ancestor Container** which matches the passed simple selector.

So, in your case button's **ancestors** are the **toolbar** and the **parent of toolbar**,but **not** the **formpanel**.Using `up()` you can get **toolbar** or **parent of toolbar**, but **not** the **formpanel**.Instead of that you can use following codes:

**First Code**

```
var formpanel = button.up(<XtypeOfToolbarParent>).down('formpanel');
```

**OR**

**Second Code**: similar to `getParent()`

```
 var formpanel = button.up().up().down('formpanel');
```

Comment: Perfect, your first option its working correctly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you opted for this choice. Anyways, your need can be achieved in few lines only. First add a class to your formpanel(If not any). For e.g. `cls: 'form-panel'`

In controller, take the reference of xtype of the container which contains the form. Say for example `formContainer: 'formcontainer'`

Now you can catch the formpanel with this line in controller:

`this.getFormContainer().element.down('.form-panel');`

Tell me it helps you or not.

Comment: Can you copy paste the full view and controller code here.